# Where is this strange character coming from in my HTML

Tags: html, css

I am seeing this character(see image. just before 0 day left) in a DIV. I even removed all text (using chrome developer tools and it stays there) Any ideas what might be causing this?

I have tried setting different charset but of no use.

[image]

Comment: Could you post the HTML for the div?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a jsFiddle?

Comment: It is on this page http://sponsor-me-awards.biz/campaigns/compaing-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is supposed to be an icon inside a pseudo-element that isn't showing up.

Either the icon font isn't loading, the "content" code is incorrect or that character does not exist in the font.

```
.project_sb_date_rem::before {
font-family: 'typicons';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
speak: none;
display: inline-block;
width: 1.2em;
height: 1.2em;
font-size: 1.2em;
text-align: center;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-smoothing: antialiased;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
content: '\e036';
}
```

Comment: I get a red empty box and not that symbol that you showed.